# "Exact duplicate" lookup on Blur

Tags: feature-request, status-norepro, close-reasons, duplicate-questions, usability

Can you trigger the look-up when the textfield's blur event is raised? Often times I'll copy/paste the id of the duplicate question, and then click off of the textbox...and nothing happens. I then have to click back in, add a space to the end, delete the space and then it does the lookup.

Can we have the same lookup functionality triggered on blur as well?

Comment: Is this one of those mod tool things? If so, isn't there a tag for that?

Comment: I used to have that problem, but not recently... Are you sure it hasn't been fixed?

Comment: I just tried it, which brought me here to asking about it.

Comment: @Random, this is not a mod-tool. It's just the input-field when you close a question as being an exact-duplicate.

Comment: Oh, okay, that's in that 3K tier isn't it?

Comment: @Random, ah, yeah, I think you're right. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I have the same issue.  The very least give a button to do the search.

Comment: The dupe UI makes me WANT TO DESTROY SOMETHING BEAUTIFUL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW, the automatic lookup *almost always* works for me. But, *when it doesn't*, there's a little trick you might find helpful:

With focus in the entryfield, **hit the down-arrow key**. The drop-down should appear...

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.  I usually won't vote to close for a dupe because the dialog is utterly annoying.

Not only can't you just type in the fing number, you also can't paste in a fing link.  And, when it suggests a duplicate page, you aren't offered any quick way to select it.  You have to open it in another window, grab out the title, go back, paste it in the textbox, then select it in the dropdown.

IT BUGS THE @#$& OUT OF ME.

Suggestions for fixing it:

1. Allow me to type in a number
2. If you suggest a website, give me a way to quickly select that one
3. Allow me to paste in a URL

Most annoying UI of SO.

Comment: You already can type in a number. That's the way I always do it.

Comment: you can in fact paste in a URL

Comment: voting this down because it's wrong. Tempted to delete it, because it is so very wrong. I paste in URLs all the time into the close box, and it works.

Comment: oh, and numbers work too.

Answer (score 0):

Once again I will spam my Greasemonkey script that eliminates the need to do any trickery to close dupes:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21826/greasemonkey-easier-vote-to-close-for-duplicates