# Allow to fast search within duplicated closing window

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, duplicate-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Duplicate Question Search Doesn’t Search Questions any more](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53079/duplicate-question-search-doesnt-search-questions-any-more)

When I see a duplicated question I remeber there is already a similar question somewhere (I could remeber the title sometimes, too).

So I click vote -> close -> and the window now asks me the id or the url.
Wouldn't it better if that window allowed me to enter some keyword for a fast search within that window?

This way I would have voted to close many more duplicates

Sure, the automatic suggestions are good, but may times they don't find the right question.

Comment: It already shows automagically-chosen similar posts. But those are half the time not it, so I support this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this used to be possible, judging from an early screenshot that I cannot find at the moment.