# Suggestion to make duplicate finding/closing easier: Add search box inside close dialog

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, duplicate-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Duplicate Question Search Doesn’t Search Questions any more](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53079/duplicate-question-search-doesnt-search-questions-any-more)

Sometimes you open a question and you just know that it has been asked many many times before.

I click on "Close as duplicate", just hoping that I will find something obvious in the "Similar posts list". After a brief scan of the list, I see nothing that matches. I know that this has been asked before, but maybe the keywords in the post aren't close enough that it matches.

At this point, the usability is kind of a mess for what to do next.

I can either:

- open up a brand new window, retype the SO url, and do a manual search, and copy the URL
- or, I can close the dialog box, search, copy URL, click back, and go through the dialog flow again.

Neither of these options is particularly appealing, and at this point I'm pretty close to just moving on and letting someone else worry about it.

So I was thinking maybe we could have a simple search box right on the dialog form? Then I could enter my own keywords which might have a better chance of matching, and close it right from the dialog window.

[image]

Comment: as a follow-up to this question, i think it would be interesting to track the number of duplicated questions over time, and show that they are increasing

Comment: @AndreaCapiluppi Like listing within this new feature a number next to the question title (i.e. `"Question ABC (5 [[other duplicates to this question]])"`? If so, I like it!

Comment: You could have a fairly good go with banning questions that would be included in a search on [mysql_fetch, boolean and given](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql_fetch+boolean+given).

Comment: +1, thank you for the initiative. A great fraction of new users is unwilling to even scan the related questions they get suggested, sometimes even with close to verbatim of their own quetion.