# Text Search in Close duplicate box

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, duplicate-questions, close-reasons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Duplicate Question Search Doesn’t Search Questions any more](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53079/duplicate-question-search-doesnt-search-questions-any-more)

I was just trying to close a duplicate without looking up the duplicate first. I've just gotten used to typing in search boxes like Google and having relevant links come up. It turns out the search box in the `close as duplicate` dialog doesn't have this functionality. It wants a question id in there somewhere.

**How about enabling real-time text searches for that box, so that it updates the list as you type words in?**

[image: Close Duplicate dialog]

Comment: This is a [first world problem](http://www.quickmeme.com/meme/3s5cq5/) if I ever I saw one... :P **WANT!**

Comment: Do these come from the related questions list?

Comment: I don't know how it comes up with it now, but I wouldn't have a problem with it using that for a text search.

Comment: @Jim, the third fix was good, thanks; but please leave my proper two-spaces after periods in there in the future.  I'm not willing to enter the casual 'type like we text' world yet.